# Multiple Dictionary Output

Tags: loops, dictionary, flask, jinja2

There is a section that is running on my flask server, and the HTML file itself. I'm trying to create a sort of results area, where it will display various parts of the dictionary. The code is working, but I'm only able to show a single result instead of multiple results. Any help to show the rest of the dictionary results on the page, instead of a single one will be helpful. Thanks.
(I didn't show the full code on my last question)

```
@app.route('/results')
 def results():
        parameters = {
            "product_type": "blush"
        }
        response = requests. Get(API, json=parameters)
        # print(response.status_code)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        for item in data:
            brand=item["brand"],
            name = item["name"],
            price = item["price"],
            description = item['description'],
            product_link = item["product_link"],
            website_link = item["website_link"],
            tags = item["tag_list"]
    
            return render_template('results.html',brand=brand, name=name, price=price, description=description, product_link=product_link,
                               website_link=website_link, tags=tags)
    
    
    
    {% include 'header.html' %}
    
    
    <body>
        <section id="results">
                <h1 class="results-heading">Search Results</h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="contents">
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Brand: </strong>{{ brand }}</p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Name: </strong>{{ name }}</p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Product Price: </strong>
                        {% if price %}
                        ${{ price.split('.')[0] }}
                        {% else %}
                            Not available
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Product Description: </strong>{{ description }}</p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Product Link: </strong><a href="{{ product_link }}">{{ product_link }}</a></p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Website Link: </strong><a href="{{ website_link }}">{{ website_link }}</a></p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Relevant Tags: </strong>
                        {% if tags %}
                            {% for tag in tags %}
                                {{ tag }},
                             {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            No Tags
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>
                </div>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "return" statement is in the for loop, so it will terminate after the first interaction.

You can run the for loop in the template and pass the list to the render_template

Answer (score 0):

Send data to template and then loop through each item in data, using jinja

```
@app.route('/results')
 def results():
        parameters = {
            "product_type": "blush"
        }
        response = requests. Get(API, json=parameters)
        # print(response.status_code)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
    
        return render_template('results.html', data=data)



{% include 'header.html' %}


<body>
    <section id="results">
            <h1 class="results-heading">Search Results</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="contents">
                {% for item in data %}

                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Brand: </strong>{{ item["brand"] }}</p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Name: </strong>{{ item["name"] }}</p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Product Price: </strong>
                        {% if item["price"] %}
                            ${{ item["price"].split('.')[0] }}
                        {% else %}
                            Not available
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Product Description: </strong>{{ item['description'] }}</p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Product Link: </strong><a href="{{ product_link }}">{{ item["product_link"] }}</a></p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Website Link: </strong><a href="{{ website_link }}">{{ item["website_link"] }}</a></p>
                    <p class="content-title"><strong>Relevant Tags: </strong>
                        {% if item["tag_list"] %}
                            {% for tag in item["tag_list"] %}
                                {{ tag }},
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            No Tags
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>

                {% endfor %}

                

            </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't show any result at all. I'm confused.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I realised my mistake.

Comment: @EmmanuellaNdukwe-Obiukwu I'm glad I could help! Here's a link that explains what is customary to do when someone answers your question in a helpful way -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time 
Cheers